# Disable Gmail's highlighting of the search query in the email's body

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, user-interface

Sometimes I search for an old email in Gmail for the purpose of taking a screenshot, but I would like to remove the yellow highlighting that is added to every match of the search query:

[image: the email body with the search term highlighted]

Can I disable it and how?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The option to disable the highlighting ("*Turn off highlighting*") is located in the "**More**" menu (indicated with three vertical dots: "**⋮**") between the search box and the email title

[image]

Comment: A really big thank you for this!

Comment: An animated gif is worth a thousand words..

Comment: i feel stupid now.

Answer (score 8):

With the most recent Gmail UI, the menu item has changed to an icon which you never would guess toggled highlighting until you actually hover over it to get the help text. It's in the top-right corner next to the printer icon.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option. I wonder if it was an A/B test

Comment: I don't have the option either.. really infuriating. As a workaround if you have basic web dev skills you can right click a highlighted word, click inspect, and you should see the CSS class that makes the highlight. Just uncheck the background color and it remove all the highlights for that page

Comment: @jeffcarey it's still showing up for me. Do you have the printer and "Open in new window" icons? The only non-obfuscated property on the div is its title; if you open the console w/ highlighting active does this return anything? `document.querySelector('[title="Turn off highlighting"]');`